# VisualStudio suggests deleting this-Keyword in important place?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, this, shadowing

Like the title says, VisualStudio 17 (15.7.1) suggests deleting a "unnecessary" this which from my understanding actually IS important.

Let's say we have following minimalistic Class:

```
class ThisExampleClass
{
    public int ThisTest1 { get; set; }
    public int ThisTest2 { get; set; }

    public ThisExampleClass()
    { }

    public ThisExampleClass(int ThisTest1, int ThisTest2)
    {
        this.ThisTest1 = ThisTest1;
        this.ThisTest2 = ThisTest2;
    }
}
```

So far so good. But if I write the following lines of code, VisualStudio 17 suggests to delete the this-Keywords.

```
class ThisExampleShowcase
{
    private int ThisTest1;
    private int ThisTest2;

    public ThisExampleShowcase()
    { }

    public void ShowQuestion()
    {
        ThisTest1 = 10;
        ThisTest2 = 11;
        var ThisTest = new ThisExampleClass()
        {
            ThisTest1 = this.ThisTest1, // delete this.
            ThisTest2 = this.ThisTest2  // delete this.
          //ThisTest2 = ThisTest2          Suggested but seems wrong
        };
    }
}
```

Would the compiler know which ThisTest to assign?
As far as I know this would potentially shadow variables but even if you delete the "this." everything seems to be ok.

Does C# and .NET automatically assume a "this." meaning for the right hand side variables in this case?

Comment: Personally id name `private int ThisTest1` to `private int _thisTest1` , then `ThisTest1 = this.ThisTest1` becomes `ThisTest1 = _thisTest1`. and you'd be ready to rumble

Comment: I'd do that too, but I just got delegated to clean up some old code and stumbled upon this VS sugestion which made me wonder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would the compiler know which ThisTest to assign?

Yes. In this case, you can't use properties from the newly created object in the assignment, so there is only one `ThisTest`.

> Does C# and .NET automatically assume a "this." meaning for the right hand side variables in this case?

No. This case is a particular one since the left-hand side is a property assignment. In a regular assignment it could be ambiguous.